# How to not contain timestamp when changing state on update object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine, state-machine-workflow

I am using workflow as state machine. I want on after every update move state to `awaiting_review` but I have also `current_sign_in_at` attribute after user log in his state changes to `awaiting_review` how to avoid that?

```
before_save :needs_review, on: :update

# before_save
def needs_review
  self.state = 'awaiting_review' unless state_changed?
end

workflow do
  state :awaiting_review do
    event :accept, :transitions_to => :accepted
    event :reject, :transitions_to => :rejected
  end
  state :accepted do
    event :reject, :transitions_to => :rejected
  end
  state :rejected
end
#  sign_in_count          :integer          default(0)
#  current_sign_in_at     :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at        :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip     :string(255)
#  last_sign_in_ip        :string(255)
```

Comment: What fields updating should trigger the state change?  You could use the `changed` method to detect those specifically.

Comment: All fiels besides these which I mention in comments: [sign_in_count  ..]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def needs_review
  if (%w[sign_in_count current_sign_in_at last_sign_in_at ...] & changes).empty?
    self.state = 'awaiting_review' unless state_changed?
  end
end
```